# ReactJS Material UI disable other tabs on button click

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Have similar code with action for a Button component click in each tab

https://codesandbox.io/embed/cbn97?codemirror=1

How can I disable other tabs on Button click in current tab?

How can I pass a "disabled" property to already displayed, rendered tab component, update it?

New to ReactJS

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you mean that if you've already been on a tab, you shouldn't be able to go to that tab again? Could you expand on the use case?

Comment: I have a button in each tab that perform an operation. Once button in one tab is clicked, other tabs should become disabled until operation is complete. I suspect I have to use State. But new to ReactJS, so figured out I ask.

Comment: In that case it would be also fine to disable all tabs rights when loading? As long as you're loading you shouldn't be able to change tabs, that is the requirement right?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). And yes, try a boolean local component state to indicate that the respective operation has started and toggle it when complete. Set your MUI `Tab` `disabled` prop based on that.

Comment: @Bas van der Linden yes, if I click the Button on one tab, all should be disabled and I should not be able to change tabs until operation is complete. Thank you for your help. Great support for beginner.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've indicated in the comments that the current page may also be disabled I suggest you do something like this:

```
export default function SimpleTabs() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(false)

  const handleOperation = () => {
    setIsLoading(true)
    // Do some synchronous operation that takes time
    setIsLoading(false)
  }
  
  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Tabs value={value} onChange={handleChange} aria-label="simple tabs example">
          <Tab label="Item One" {...a11yProps(0)} disabled={isLoading}/>
          <Tab label="Item Two" {...a11yProps(1)} disabled={isLoading}/>
          <Tab label="Item Three" {...a11yProps(2)} disabled={isLoading}/>
        </Tabs>
      </AppBar>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
        <button onClick={handleOperation}>start operation</button>
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
        Item Two
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={2}>
        Item Three
      </TabPanel>
    </div>
  );
}
```

So the approach above is to create an `isLoading` state that identifies whether one of your tab button operations is in progress. Inside your tab button handler function(s) set `isLoading` to `true` making the tabs disabled and set `isLoading` to `false` after the operation is done.

Answer (score 0):

Just put result of functions with conditions to `disabled` prop of your tabs:

```
export default function SimpleTabs() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
  const [operationDone, setOperationDone] = React.useState(false)

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };
  
  const isDisabled = (tabIndex) => {
    if(operationDone) {
      return false;
    }
    else {
      if(value !== tabIndex) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Tabs value={value} onChange={handleChange} aria-label="simple tabs example">
          <Tab label="Item One" disabled={isDisabled(0)} {...a11yProps(0)} />
          <Tab label="Item Two" disabled={isDisabled(1)} {...a11yProps(1)} />
          <Tab label="Item Three" disabled={isDisabled(2)} {...a11yProps(2)} />
        </Tabs>
      </AppBar>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
        <button onClick={() => setOperationDone(true)}>change operation done</button>
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
        Item Two
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={2}>
        Item Three
      </TabPanel>
    </div>
  );
}
```